# cups-browsed service, thunderbird and others apps cannot start due to "libgio-2.0.so.0"

Tags: services

cups-browsed service, thunderbird and others apps cannot start due to "libgio-2.0.so.0"
what to do?

```
elias@eliasc:~/Downloads/_LINUX_PKGS$ thunderbird 
XPCOMGlueLoad error for file /usr/lib/thunderbird/libmozgtk.so:
libgio-2.0.so.0: failed to map segment from shared object
Couldn't load XPCOM.
elias@eliasc:~/Downlo

elias@eliasc:~/Downloads/_LINUX_PKGS$ sudo /sbin/ldconfig -v | grep libgio
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Can't stat /usr/local/lib/i386-linux-gnu: Δεν υπάρχει τέτοιο αρχείο ή κατάλογος
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu' given more than once
(from /etc/ld.so.conf.d/i386-linux-gnu.conf:4 and /etc/ld.so.conf.d/i386-linux-gnu.conf:3)
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Can't stat /usr/local/lib/i686-linux-gnu: Δεν υπάρχει τέτοιο αρχείο ή κατάλογος
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Can't stat /lib/i686-linux-gnu: Δεν υπάρχει τέτοιο αρχείο ή κατάλογος
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Can't stat /usr/lib/i686-linux-gnu: Δεν υπάρχει τέτοιο αρχείο ή κατάλογος
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
(from /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu.conf:3 and /etc/ld.so.conf.d/libreoffice6.2.conf:1)
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
(from /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu.conf:4 and /etc/ld.so.conf.d/libreoffice6.2.conf:1)
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/usr/lib32' given more than once
(from /etc/ld.so.conf.d/zz_i386-biarch-compat.conf:3 and /etc/ld.so.conf.d/zz_i386-biarch-compat.conf:2)
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/usr/libx32' given more than once
(from /etc/ld.so.conf.d/zz_x32-biarch-compat.conf:3 and /etc/ld.so.conf.d/zz_x32-biarch-compat.conf:2)
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
(from <builtin>:0 and /etc/ld.so.conf.d/libreoffice6.2.conf:1)
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
(from <builtin>:0 and /etc/ld.so.conf.d/libreoffice6.2.conf:1)
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/usr/lib' given more than once
(from <builtin>:0 and <builtin>:0)
    libgio-2.0.so.0 -> libgio-2.0.so.0.6800.1
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.33.so is the dynamic linker, ignoring

/sbin/ldconfig.real: Cannot stat /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgiomm-2.4.so: Δεν υπάρχει τέτοιο αρχείο ή κατάλογος
    libgio-qt.so.0 -> libgio-qt.so.0.0.1
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.33.so is the dynamic linker, ignoring

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /lib32/ld-2.33.so is the dynamic linker, ignoring

    libgio-2.0.so.0 -> libgio-2.0.so.0.6400.4
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /lib/ld-lsb.so.3 is the dynamic linker, ignoring

elias@eliasc:~/Downloads/_LINUX_PKGS$ ldconfig -p | grep libgio
    libgio-2.0.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0
    libgio-2.0.so.0 (libc6) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0
    libgio-2.0.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so
    libgio-qt.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-qt.so.0
    libgio-qt.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-qt.so
elias@eliasc:~/Downloads/_LINUX_PKGS$ sudo /usr/sbin/cups-browsed -v
/usr/sbin/cups-browsed: error while loading shared libraries: libgio-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
elias@eliasc:~/Downloads/_LINUX_PKGS$ sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-0


elias@eliasc:~/Downloads/_LINUX_PKGS$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by finding that LD PATH was empty.
by running `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Therefore, i edited ~/.bashrc `sudo medit ~/.bashrc` adding at the very end of the file:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/thunderbird/:"$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/bin/thunderbird/:"$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
```

however, thunderbird is the only desktop app that is not running by clicking its desktop icon while it is running through terminal!!! I have made another post.